# As of Rails 5, when is :inverse_of necessary to set manually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I've read in various places that it gets automatically inferred in some circumstances, but I've found the documentation on this feature to be hard to follow. Can anyone shed some light on the principles? **Specifically when will Rails be able to infer and when will Rails not be able infer inverses?**

I'd like to consider

- polymorphic associations
- single tabled inheritance (e.g. where `BundleProduct` and `IndividualProduct` both inherit from `Product` and use a `products` table)
- regular has_one/has_many/belongs_to associations
- has many through: associations

**Some context:** I'm maintaining a reasonably large 9-year-old Rails application with many, many tables. I'd like to have some guidance on which models require addition of `inverse_of:` rather than having to change every model in the system.

Comment: Please check here (maybe you did already, anyway..): https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations, precisely: "By including the `:inverse_of option` in the has_many association declaration, Active Record will now recognize the bi-directional association:...". And also https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to, https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-one. Or maybe you can narrow your question with an example.

Comment: I added a bit more context to the question so you can understand my predicament.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> If you do not set the :inverse_of record, the association will do its
>   best to match itself up with the correct inverse. Automatic inverse
>   detection only works on has_many, has_one, and belongs_to
>   associations.
>   -- [Rails API docs - ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)

In cases where you have "non-standard" naming you may however need to provide the option:

> The automatic guessing of the inverse association uses a heuristic
>   based on the name of the class, so it may not work for all
>   associations, especially the ones with non-standard names.
>   -- [Rails API docs - ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)

For example:

```
class Pet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pets
end
```

If we call `pet.owner` it may incur a database hit even if we have already loaded that record.

If we add the `inverse_of` option:

```
class Pet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :pets
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pets, inverse_of: :owner
end
```

Now if we already have that `owner` record in memory then `pet.owner` will point to the same `owner`.

In general there is no harm in explicitly setting the `inverse_of` so you can set it for each case where you are unsure. You can also manually test if it is needed by seeing if [accessing the assocation creates a DB query via the console](https://www.viget.com/articles/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations/) or by using [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) with your test suite.

Answer (score 3):

You can look up exact inferring procedure in [ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection#automatic_inverse_of](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ea65d92f1924648e72f93bb0e8e5fc62a56d0bac/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L614).

Rails tries to detect inverse for `has_many`, `has_one` and `belongs_to` that do not have `through`, `foreign_key` options and scope and have standard names (this is also described in [official guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations)).

Comment: Note that the behavior of the code in the link has changed.  The part that looks up plural associations was [reverted](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/42d20e8de55eff9462fa55afdf98c950f7b0709d), which means it won't automatically infer `has_many` associations with a plural name (so, all of them?).  This is the behavior in Rails 6 and 7.